# Where do current developments go regarding graphical displays for devices?

Tags: display, development, 3.3v

Our company is currently redesigning a piece of measurement equipment. We have looked at what display we have currently (It's a generic 240 by 64 pixel graphic LCD like [this one](http://www.powertip.com.tw/products_2.php?product_id=1170987886&area_idbk=1170780372) ) and if there is any chance we can get a replacement which runs on 3V3, offers serial input and which is not near its End Of Life. The main problem is that we are switching from a 5V microcontroller to a 3V3 microcontroller and therefore our system voltage drops down to 3V3. It also saves a lot of pins moving from an old 6800 interface to a fast SPI interface.

Unfortunately I don't know where the display industry developments go and which products will be supported for a long time (read: just have been developed and brought to market). I'm aware that this is a very broad question and may not be answerable. I have failed to narrow it down though.

Where do the trends go and which display format has just started to come up? Chip on Glass? Display on Glass?

Comment: Although this is a good and important question commercially, it's not a good fit for the SE format. Certain formats of QVGA TFT (color) panels have a good chance of longevity.